# Does MVC-3 include a library for composing rich (HTML) emails quickly and automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I'd like my MVC-3 application to send out nicely formatted status emails. Is there a standard library that I can use to handle the dirty work?

Comment: What kind of dirty work are you thinking about? You could just use partials as body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, MVC does not include anything related to sending emails.  But it doesn't need to, because this functionality is built into .NET.  There are many many many tutorials on how to send html emails in .NET.  It's not a lot of code to do it either.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150716/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080206-1.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211016215613/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080801-1.shtml

http://www.search-this.com/2009/02/05/aspnet-sending-email-both-in-html-and-plain-text/

etc.. etc.. etc...

There are various third party libraries that improve things, such as MvcMailer, FluentEmail, etc.. Just search for email in NuGet and see the list.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)